# Добавление расчётного столбца в таблицу строго-типизированного dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

У меня есть 2 таблицы в строго-типизированном датасете ShopDB. Таблица Orders соединена внешним ключом FK_Employees_Orders с таблицей Employees по полю EmployeeID:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Передо мной стоит задача, вывести общее количество продаж по каждому из сотрудников. (сделать что-то типа LEFT JOIN, но я хочу решить задачу иначе).
Вот мой код:

```
ShopDB shopDB = new ShopDB();
var employeesTableAdapter = new ShopDBTableAdapters.EmployeesTableAdapter();
employeesTableAdapter.Fill(shopDB.Employees);

var ordersTableAdapter = new ShopDBTableAdapters.OrdersTableAdapter();
ordersTableAdapter.Fill(shopDB.Orders);

ShopDB.EmployeesDataTable employees = employeesTableAdapter.GetData();
ShopDB.OrdersDataTable orders = ordersTableAdapter.GetData();
employees.Columns.Add("AggregateColumn", typeof(double), "Count(Child(FK_Orders_Employees).EmployeeID)"); /*название отношения взял из определения ShopDB.Designer.cs*/

 foreach (DataRow employeeRow in employees.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn employeeColumn in employees.Columns)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", employeeColumn.ColumnName, employeeRow[employeeColumn]);
```

При отладке, на строке с добавлением колонки возникает исключительная ситуация:[image: Ошибка]

**System.Data.EvaluateException HResult=0x80131920 Сообщение = Не привязанная ссылка в составном выражении "System.Data.AggregateNode". Источник = System.Data Трассировка стека: в System.Data.AggregateNode.Eval(DataRow row, DataRowVersion version) в System.Data.DataExpression.Evaluate(DataRow row, DataRowVersion version) в System.Data.DataTable.EvaluateExpressions(DataColumn column) в System.Data.DataColumn.set_Expression(String value) в System.Data.DataColumnCollection.AddAt(Int32 index, DataColumn column) в System.Data.DataColumnCollection.Add(String columnName, Type type, String expression)**

Не подскажете, какое может быть тут решение?

Comment: Вы хотите расчетное значение в базу затолкать?

Comment: @Yaroslav, нет, достаточно увидеть будет в автономной модели

Comment: так тогда зачем его в dataset помещать?

Comment: @Yaroslav, давайте затолкаем в TableAdapter. Мне без разницы куда его затолкать, лишь бы можно было циклом пробежаться по таблице и показать нужные мне столбцы. Изменения в БД отправлять не нужно

Comment: сделайте сложную выборку с подзапросами, join'ами или есть еще linq

Comment: прокомментируйте Ваши таблички

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT EMP.*,
                COUNT(ORD.ORDERID) OVER (PARTITION BY ORD.EMPLOYEESID) AS COUNT_ORDERS
  FROM EMPLOYEES EMP
    LEFT JOIN ORDERS ORD
      ON ORD.EMPLOYEESID = EMP.EMPLOYEESID;

Comment: @Yaroslav - вы пишете sql-запрос, а человеку нужно выражение в колонке DataTable.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, трудности прикрутить к DataTable на клиенте, не должно составить

Comment: @Yaroslav - [DataColumn.Expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2#expression-syntax) поддерживает весьма ограниченный набор операторов. Это не полноценная база данных и не полноценный sql.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, а что если с базы выбрать данные, сделать аналитику а потом уже вставить DataTable

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, Вы удалили свое сообщение, не могли бы помочь решить задачу. я изменил всё, как вы сказали,описал проблему. Извините, если долго это делал.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, спасибо, что хоть попытались помочь

Comment: Я удалил ответ, потому что он был неправильным. Чем ещё помочь, не знаю. Честно говоря, не хочется возиться с созданием типизированного датасета. Единственно, что приходит в голову - не правильно указано имя relation в строке column expression. Я не знаю - оно генерируется автоматически или можно задать самостоятельно?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, автоматически) задать самостоятельно можно только в обычном dataset. Меня порадовало, что Вы откликнулись и вникли в мой вопрос, что прочитали про DataColumn.Expression. Это форум и все мы тут делимся знаниями, опытом, идеями. Удалять не нужно было. Название отношения я брал из автоматически-сгенерированного кода CLR, но ошибка не уходила. Тем не менее, я решил задачу при помощи Linq, не используя отношения. Если интересно, пожалуйста ознакомьтесь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я получил то, что я хотел. Отказался от отношений, воспользовался Linq и всё получилось:

```
        ShopDB shopDB = new ShopDB();

        var employeesTableAdapter = new ShopDBTableAdapters.EmployeesTableAdapter();
        employeesTableAdapter.Fill(shopDB.Employees);

        var ordersTableAdapter = new ShopDBTableAdapters.OrdersTableAdapter();
        ordersTableAdapter.Fill(shopDB.Orders);

        var orderDetailsTableAdapter = new ShopDBTableAdapters.OrderDetailsTableAdapter();
        orderDetailsTableAdapter.Fill(shopDB.OrderDetails);

        ShopDB.EmployeesDataTable employees = employeesTableAdapter.GetData();
        ShopDB.OrdersDataTable orders = ordersTableAdapter.GetData();

        employees.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));
        foreach (DataRow employeeRow in employees.Rows)
        {
            employeeRow["Count"] = orders.Count(o => o.EmployeeID == (int)employeeRow["EmployeeID"]);

            foreach (DataColumn column in employees.Columns) {
                if (column.ColumnName=="EmployeeID" || column.ColumnName == "Count")
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", column.ColumnName, employeeRow[column]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а зря Вы отказались от отношений, это нарушение безопасности
и где Linq

Comment: @Yaroslav, где строка с лямбда-выражением. Возможно Вы правы, но я не знал, как обойти эту ошибку, используя отношения

Comment: я Вам sql запрос в комментариях писал, просто переведите его на C#. Результат может у Вас и правильный, но не совсем лаконично как то написано. Можно здесь посмотреть: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9980568/10384085